# How to use libraries built with MacPorts in a bundle

Tags: bundle, macports

I have 32-bit Mono application that depends on several external libraries built with macports. They are located in /opt/loca/lib and I need to find a way to put them into bundle directory without breaking them.

Is it possible to change macports library dependency paths from absolute to relative?